# How do i run a python program just by typing the script name on windows 10 cmd line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, cmd

How do i run a python program just by typing the script name on windows 10 cmd line?
Also without having to change directory. I already added my scripts folder and python folder to the path.
tried also tu run assoc py.=PythonScript
ftype PythonScript=python.exe %1 %*

Here's the program's content:

```
#! python3
# mapIt.py  - Launches a map in the browser using an address from the command line or clipboard
import webbrowser, sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    address = ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])
else:
    address = pyperclip.paste()

webbrowser.open('https://www.google.com/maps/place/' + address)
```

I added a screenshot with all the commands i tried so far.[image]

Comment: `python mapIt.py` seems to have worked. It looks like though that the script just doesn't do anything. Also, please post everything as text instead of images.

Comment: I think the program might actually be running correctly, but then giving you an error message. Can you post the contents of `mapIt.py`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate or it does something but outputs nothing.

Comment: To avoid changing directories you can use the file path, in your case the command would be `python .\scripts\mapIt.py` (this one only works when you are running it from the `C:\Users\Tommaso` directory) or  `python C:\Users\Tommaso\scripts\mapIt.py` (this command will work at directory)

Comment: it is working but just after i cd to scripts and call it by using python mapIt.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is to run the file 'mapIt.py' without invoking the keyword python that is:

```
>mapIt.py
```

instead of

```
>python mapIt.py
```

the way to do that in Linux or macOS is simple enough, you can add

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

to the top of the file, rename your file from mapIt.py to mapIt
make the script executable:

```
chmod +x mapIt
```

But for windows there is no straightforward solution.

One way you can do it is convert the file into an exe or

first add a python.exe association for all '.py' files

```
> assoc .py=Python
```

and then

```
> ftype Python="<path of your python.exe>" "%1" %*
```

replace the text in angular brackets (<>) with the path of your python.exe file.

Comment: yes i forgot to include ````#! python3```` at the beginning of the script and now i can make it work from everywhere bu still typing the .py extencion; I am happy with that but would be better to know hot to do it without

Comment: I already did ````assoc py.=PythonScript  
ftype PythonScript=python.exe %1 %*````

Comment: There is no way to do it without the .py extension, also if you feel like my answer was what you needed please choose it as the correct answer.